# How can I make a nested category system?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to make a category system. My attempt is to use enum of enums. I have a class called `Tile`. My `Tile` class also has a `Type type;` variable.

When I try and declare `type = Type.Wall.BOTTOM;` (or `type = Type.Floor.CROOKED;`) it states that the required type was `Type` but the type found was `Wall` (or `Floor`).

Specifically, I am trying to categorizing of Tiles in a game. Some tiles are wall some are floor. A wall can be `x,y,x`, a floor can be `1,2,3`. So `tile` can be `wall.x` or `floor.1`. From this, I can know the exact type (by which I mean including the sub-type so that I can draw the correct tile texture on the screen) and sometimes I only need to know the type so that I know if the tile is walkable or not.

This is what I have done:

```
public enum Type {
    ;

    public enum Wall {
        TOP_LEFT, TOP, TOP_RIGHT,
        LEFT, RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        NORTH_EAST, NORTH_WEST,
        SOUTH_EAST, SOUTH_WEST
    }

    public enum Floor {
        CROOKED,
        WOOD
    }
}
```

How can I design this to work for my case ?

Comment: You can't.  "An enum of enums" is not a thing that makes sense.  You could have one `Type` `enum` and a `Set` of the `Type` elements that are walls, but the type system doesn't work like that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Great. Then how would you design something like this ? The `Type` can be `Wall` or `Floor`. If it is `Wall` there are a few options. If it is `Floor` there are other kind of options. How would I set this up ?

Comment: @Shiro plain classes??

Comment: Put everything in `Type`; give each `Type` a `TypeType`, with `enum TypeType { FLOOR, WALL; }`.  That's probably as close as you're going to get.  (Also, `Type` is a terrible name.)

Comment: `public class Type` or better yet, put them all in some sort of namespace, rather than a class or enum.

Comment: How about in your enum, namespace your types? Ex: WALL_TOP_LEFT, WALL_TOP, WALL_TOP_RIGHT, ... , FLOOR_TOP, FLOOR_TOP_LEFT etc

Comment: @Shiro you wouldn't be able to know. If you need the types to behave differently, don't have them all in one enum

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If you describe your actual requirement instead of how you are currently trying to solve it, you may get more helpful answers.

Comment: Make sure everyone can see that info by editing your original post.

Comment: @sstan I suppose the only thing that differs is the title of my question, since my code is just an attempt.

Comment: Maybe something that would be useful is being a bit clearer on how you expect to use/read the `type` variable inside your `Tile` class (even if it doesn't compile, just as an example). You seem to want to hold both a type and subtype all in one, but I'm not clear on how you want to use that.

Comment: @sstan I want to know the type of the `Tile` which consists of knowing both the type and the sub-type to draw a texture on the screen. And sometimes I just want to know the type, to identify if the tile is floor (walkable) or wall (not walkable)

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I follow that then I won't be able to iterate through all Walls or Floors. I suppose a way to put it is that I want a category system for a few static final strings. Which is why enum of enums, made sense for me as a first idea. The accepted answer is a good example of what I need, but I am not sure if it is possible to implement a deeper tree, if that was required later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still have doubts as to whether I'm understanding the question correctly, but if you are willing to use `instanceof` to check for the type, and would then be willing to perform a cast to get the subtype information, then you can do this with an interface shared by your different enums.

```
public interface Type {
}

public enum Wall implements Type {

    TOP_LEFT, TOP, TOP_RIGHT,
    LEFT, RIGHT,
    BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
    NORTH_EAST, NORTH_WEST,
    SOUTH_EAST, SOUTH_WEST
}

public enum Floor implements Type {

    TOP_LEFT,
    TOP
}
```

Which would then allow you to write code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Type t = Wall.BOTTOM;
    System.out.println(t instanceof Wall);
    System.out.println(((Wall)t) == Wall.BOTTOM);

    t = Floor.TOP_LEFT;
    System.out.println(t instanceof Floor);
    System.out.println(((Floor)t) == Floor.TOP_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about what your `Tile` class is going to do.

1. It's going to interact with `Wall` in one way, and `Floor` in a completely different way
2. It's going to do whatever else that it will do irrespective of `Wall` and `Floor`.

Therefore, the right thing to do is **encapsulate that behavior** away from `Tile` entirely.

I'm going to use really crappy names here, because you haven't provided a use case, so I'll do the best I can.

```
public class Tile {
  private PartOfRoom part;

  public Tile(PartOfRoom part) {
    this.part = part;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    part.doSomething();
    doSomethingThatDoesntUsePart();
  }

  public boolean isWalkable() {
    return part.isWalkable();
  }
}
```

Then you can have:

```
public interface PartOfRoom {
  void doSomething();
}

public class FloorPartOfRoom {
  private final Floor floor;

  FloorPartOfRoom(Floor floor) {
    this.floor = floor;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    floor.paint();
  }
}

public class WallPartOfRoom() {
  private final Wall wall; 

  WallPartOfRoom(Wall wall) {
    this.wall = wall;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    wall.mop();
  }
}
```

Comment: I could just have a **list of lists of lists** to organize a few final static values (which is exactly what enum does and the reason why I am using it) to make a **type, sub-type, sub-sub-type** system and so on. I am not trying to put any functionality to those values. It is simply an enum. A final static string value. So, all I tried to do is make a **enum of enums of enums** with the same mindset, however didn't find a way to make it work.

Comment: If I wanted to make this work following kind of your approach, I would make 2 classes,  `Wall` and `Floor` which extend `Tile` and each of those 2 classes would have an `enum Type`. But this would be awkward because the only thing that differs on `Wall` and `Floor` is the `enum Type` values.

Comment: If that's the only thing that's different then you don't even need instanceof, you can just use a common interface which was my very first answer. Whatever

Comment: If I use a common interface for the Wall and Floor enums, then I have to use instanceof to check if the type is Wall or Floor. What do you mean I don't even need instanceof ?

Comment: @Shiro because you don't actually care, you only care if it's `.isWalkable()`

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the enum of enum types and just applying basic OOAD techniques for this requirement:

> I am trying to categorizing of Tiles in a game. Some tiles are wall
>   some are floor. A wall can be x,y,x, a floor can be 1,2,3. So tile can
>   be wall.x or floor.1. From this, I can know the exact type (by which I
>   mean including the sub-type so that I can draw the correct tile
>   texture on the screen) and sometimes I only need to know the type so
>   that I know if the tile is walkable or not.

```
abstract class Tile {
    abstract boolean isWalkable();
}

class Wall extends Tile {

    public enum WallPosition {
        TOP_LEFT, TOP, TOP_RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM, BOTTOM_RIGHT, NORTH_EAST, NORTH_WEST, SOUTH_EAST, 
        SOUTH_WEST
    }

    @Override boolean isWalkable() {
        return false;
    }

}

class Floor extends Tile {
    public enum FloorType {
        CROOKED, WOOD
    }

    @Override boolean isWalkable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am assuming that you might have common state for both `Wall` and `Tile` - reason for using an abstract class. Otherwise it can just be an interface.